# Get rid of extra space on top of QLabel

Tags: qt, user-interface, qt4, padding, qlabel

As shown by the picture below, I have a QLabel with unwanted whitespace between the "Actual definition" and the text in the QLabel. I've tried setting the vertical alignment to `AlignTop`, setting the style sheet to `QLabel{padding: 0 0 0 0px;}`, but this is the end result:

[image: awww man]

How can I fix this?

**EDIT** While creating a test UI file, I discovered that the cause behind this was my setting the indent to `15`. How can I keep the indent to the right without causing the indent to the bottom (and while keeping the alignment of the text to the top of the label)? [It seems as if I can't just use indent anymore](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qlabel.html#indent-prop).

Comment: Looks like you have a newline character at the start

Comment: @Tony unfortunately it's not that simple. Debug output shows no newline, and removing the first character of the label text has no effect other than omitting the first character actually seen.

Comment: Is the border part of the QLabel ? Did you try setting the margins to 0 with both (`QLabel {padding:0; margin:0}`) and `yourLabel->setContentsMargins(QMargins())` ?

Comment: Maybe you could post some code?

Comment: @alexisdm Yep, I put a border on the QLabel so I could see if the label was causing the whitespace. I tried both `setContentsMargins(QMargins(0, 0, 0, 0))` and just `setContentsMargins(QMargins())`; neither seem to have any effect

Comment: @arlen I'm not sure which code to post, my settings are pretty much all done in QtDesigner

Comment: You could post a minimal .ui file that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @alexisdm ahhh I was doing just that when I found out that the problem was that I set my indent to 15. I do want the indent to the right as shown, but I do not want the indent to the bottom. What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `indent`, try using `padding-left` in a style sheet.

Comment: Ahhh, so effectively simple! Thanks so much!

Comment: I tried this but it won't work, I have some extra space in QLabel text and border.